# Pronouncing aloud the end of the gaal yisroael bracha before amida?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Sometimes the person leading scharit davening does not pronounce aloud the end of the last bracha before the silent amida (gaal yisroael).  This is to not introduce an interruption between the bracha and the amida when people who hear the bracha say amen. There is a practice of daveners trying to complete that bracha at the same time as the leader, to avoid the obligation to say amen.  What is the halachic status of the practice of the leader not audibly saying the last words of that bracha?  Is it correct or incorrect or are there discrepant views that are all legitimate?

Comment: It is incorrect, as it leaves listeners who are being Yotzei from the Chazzan out in the dark, effectively having the Chazzan fail at his job.

Comment: @DoubleAA, if you have an answer, I suggest you post it at the other question. (Currently, no answer there says what you said in your comment here.)